# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Coordinate out of bounds setRGB

Tags: java, image, rotation

I am new to programming and I'm currently working on a program that rotates an image to the right and upside down. I was able to get the upside down method working but not the rotate to the right (90 degrees clockwise). It keeps giving me an out of bounds error, and I'm not sure why as I have looked at other examples. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's is the method that I'm working on:

```
public Image rotateRight()
{
  Image right = new Image (this);
  img = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
  int width = right.img.getWidth();
  int height = right.img.getHeight();


  for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
        {
            this.img.setRGB(height-j-1,i,right.img.getRGB(i,j));

        }
   return right;
}
```

Here's the rest of the code:

```
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.*;

public class Image {

private BufferedImage img = null;
int width;
int height;

private Image()
{
}

public Image (int w, int h)
{
    img = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB );
   width = w;
    height = h;
}

public Image (Image anotherImg)
{
width = anotherImg.img.getWidth();
    height = anotherImg.img.getHeight();
    img = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB );

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            this.img.setRGB(j,i,anotherImg.img.getRGB(j,i)) ;
        }

}


public String toString()
{
    return "Width of Image:" +width+"\nHeight of Image:"+height;
}


public Image (String filename)
{
    try
    {
        img = ImageIO.read(new File(filename));
        width = img.getWidth();
         height = img.getHeight();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
            System.out.println(e);
    }
}

public void save(String filename, String extension)
{
    try
    {
        File outputfile = new File(filename);
        ImageIO.write(img, extension, outputfile);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
public Image copy()
{
    Image copiedImage = new Image(this);
    return copiedImage;
}
```

Here's Main:

```
  public static void main (String args[])
{
    Image srcimg = new Image("apple.jpg");

    System.out.println(srcimg);

  Image copy = srcimg.copy();
    copy.save("apple-copy.jpg", "jpg");
  Image copy2 = srcimg.copy();


  Image right = copy2.rotateRight();

  right.save("apple-rotateRight.jpg", "jpg");



}
```

Comment: shouldn't your new image width be equal to original's height ? ... I  mean how about `img = new BufferedImage( height,width, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);` ... also you are using same names for local and global variables .. and it's bit confusing...  just saying.

Comment: @Plirkee Woow....that fixed my problem, I'm so angry right now, this whole time I thought the problem was with my statement in the for loops. I wasted so many hours, should have posted here a while ago.. Thank You so much :D and thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when rotating your image is as stated. Something is out of bounds. It could be either your i variable that has exceeded its bounds or your j variable that has exceeded its bounds and this is generally easy to test for by just adding a print statement within your for loop and checking which one of the two values is out of bounds. It is good practice to try to resolve these problems yourself as you will start learning what causes these and where the problem lies.

Anyways enough of my rambling. The problem that you seem to have is that you are trying to turn the image without changing the size of the image.

You are creating a new Image with the same width and height parameters as the original

```
img = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB );
```

However when you want to rotate an image by 90 degrees you actually want to flip the width and height parameters. If you think about it, it makes sense when you rotate an image by 90 degrees the width will become the height and the height will become the width.

So your problem is here:

```
this.img.setRGB(height-j-1,i,right.img.getRGB(i,j));
```

In your case the bounds for the x parameter in the setRGB function is from 0 to the WIDTH of your image and the y parameter is from 0 to the HEIGHT of your image. Therefore because your height variable is different from your width. If for example your WIDTH is 200 and your HEIGHT is 100. When you put this in to the function the greatest value for the x parameter will be:

'100 - 199 - 1 = -100' which is clearly out of bounds. However if we change your code to.

```
img = new BufferedImage(height, width, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB );
```

now when we do the same thing as before where we get the maximum possible value.

WIDTH = 100, HEIGHT = 200;

'200 - 99 - 1 = 100' which is inside the bounds